# PHP use another php.ini file then set

Tags: php-ini, php

I've intalled PHP5 with Apache web server. 
I need to use DCOM. So in php.ini file I've uncomment string `allow_dcom=true`
but when I run php `<? phpinfo(); ?>` allow_dcom set to 0. 
Also in php info config file is equal to file in what allow_dcom set to true.

As I understand php takes not valid php.ini file.

Can anybody help me to solve that?

Comment: See Loaded Configuration File path in phpinfo and accordingly change configuration of php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart the apache server after changing php.ini so that its changes reflects.

[Reference Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)